# create error: Invalid datetime format: 1292

Tags: laravel

I want to present the date in the create and edit form fields "start_date" and "end_date" in this format- 21 February 2018 - 10:00.

In the database the date fields have the type "datetime".

So in the form to create a new conference I have two date fields:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type='text'
                   name="start_date" value="{{ old('start_date') }}"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY H:m:s" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="end_date>End Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type='text' class="form-control"
                   value="{{ old('end_date') }}" name="end_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY H:m:s"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the edit form the fields are equal the only difference is that in the value attribute is: "`value="{{$conference->start_date}}`".

In the conference model I have these two methods:

```
public function getStartDateAttribute($date)
{
    return $date->format('d F Y - H:i');
}

public function getEndDateAttribute($date)
{
    return $date->format('d F Y - H:i');
}
```

Then in the store method I have the validate and create method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'start_date' => 'required|date_format:d F Y - H:i',
        'end_date' => 'required|date_format:d F Y - H:i|after_or_equal:start_date',
    ]);
   $conference = Conference::create([
        'start_date' => $request->start_date,
        'end_date' => $request->end_date,
    ]);   
    }
```

But after submiting the form it appears an error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '21 February 2018 - 10:00' for column 'start_date'
```

Do you know where is the issue?

Comment: You said: "In the conference controller I have these two methods" in controller or model ??

Comment: Sorry, in the conference model!

Comment: I updated the question with that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySql the default format for date column is Y-m-d and for datetime is Y-m-d H:i:s. So change your date then save it.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'start_date' => 'required|date_format:d F Y - H:i',
        'end_date' => 'required|date_format:d F Y - H:i|after_or_equal:start_date',
    ]);
    $conference = Conference::create([
        'start_date' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->start_date),
        'end_date' =>  Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->end_date),
    ]);   
}
```

To get the the dates field as dates not just strings you have to add the `dates` property like this :

```
protected $dates = [
        'start_date',
        'end_date'
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks, but on the edit page how the date value should be? Im using "value="{{$conference->start_date}}" but it appears "Call to a member function format() on string".

Comment: Just add start_date and end_date to the dates property in the model

Comment: I have the methods getStartDateAttribute and getEndDateAttribute also the dates are in the $fillable array, its not that?

Comment: I updated the answer, it's getEndDateAttribute that cause the problem because of this line `$date->format('d F Y - H:i');` so add dates property will solve the problem :)

Comment: Thanks but it appears the same error "Call to a member function format() on string (View: /Users/johnw/projects/proj/resources/views/conferences/edit.blade.php)"". How that $dates array can fix the issue? Im not understanding. Its necessary to change in the getEndDateAttribute method the parameter from $date to $dates?

Comment: No just add the `dates` array property at the top of the conference model !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165563/discussion-between-maraboc-and-johnz).